# Why images didn't add to the imagescontainer in ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

This is my code
If I push the button the image is showing after I press the "hot reload" button.

Question:
Why can't the images be added to the imagecontainer in `ListView`?

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Anime Randomizer'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final String title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      var urlresult = "https://danbooru.donmai.us/data/original/13/c4/13c4ee9c0f8e305fbe6a4c4efb540ec7.jpg";
      var filter = "";
      var error = "";
      var iterator = 0;
      List<Widget> imagescontainer = [new Container(child: Image.network("https://danbooru.donmai.us/data/original/13/c4/13c4ee9c0f8e305fbe6a4c4efb540ec7.jpg", width: 400, height: 650)),];
    
      void fetchAnimeUrl() async {
        var url = Uri.parse('https://danbooru.donmai.us/posts/random?tags=rating%3Asafe${filter != null ? '+'+filter: ''}&format=json');
        final response = await http.get(url);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var start = response.body.indexOf('file_url');
          var end = response.body.indexOf(',"large_file_url"');
          if(start != -1 || end != -1){
            setState(() {
              iterator++;
              urlresult = response.body.substring(start + 11, end - 1);
              error = imagescontainer.length.toString();
              imagescontainer.add(new Container(child: Image.network(urlresult.toString(), width: 300, height: 620)));
            });
          }
          else{
            setState(() {
              error = "Купить премиум - 25\$";
            });
          }
        } else {
          throw Exception('Failed to load anime');
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Anime randomizer list"),
          ),
          body: Container(
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: imagescontainer //this variable contain all my images
              ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: fetchAnimeUrl,
            tooltip: 'MoreAnime',
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_down),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `setState` after image fetch operation with empty body instead of async call inside of sync setState?

Answer (score 0):

I fix it!

```
body: Container(
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: imagescontainer.toList() //i wrote a "toList()"
              ),
          ),
```